# Git - how to get all commit messages from last merge?

Tags: git, version-control, githooks

I am currently working on a git post-merge hook. Now in this hook I need all commit messages that came in with the merge.

Does anybody have a clue how to solve this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
git log $(git merge-base HEAD^1 HEAD^2)..HEAD^2
```

Comment: I recently tried to roll out my script to production. Now I got the following error when merging: "Not a valid object name HEAD^2" Do you have an idea why this error occurs?

Comment: HEAD^2 is not valid if a commit is not a merge.  This can be solved by `git rev-parse HEAD^2 > /dev/null 2>&1`, then testing `$?`, if `0`, the commit `HEAD` is a merge.

Comment: Your check works but the problem is that I need all commits. No matter whether they are merges or not. I need to run a regex matching on all commit messages.

Comment: Any other idea @cforbish?